# why this query in MySQL do not use index?

Tags: mysql, indexing

As I am learning how to make index perform better in MySQL,I saw an example :

> if you create join index like this : (col1,col2) ;and your query like this : select col3 from table where col1 = 'col1' order by col2. the engine will not use join index to sort your data.you should sort like : select col3 from table where col1 = 'col1' order by col1,col2;

But I am confuse about the above example: if I create (col1,col2) ,it mean that the B + tree will first order index by col1,and when col1 is same it consider col2.

so in this query we have col1 = 'col1',so I think the engine just get data by join index order then the data will order by col2 naturally.

Am I wrong or this example wrong? also I hope someone could recomment an article about how to use index better,rather than teach what is index and how to add an index,

Comment: Everything is more complex than described. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7632b92cbb2ddc53aaafe00413fde335 (and even this fiddle does not cover all possible situations). Complete explanation is too long. Study execution plan building and optimization.

Comment: ok,I will look the link seriously,thank you.

Comment: In that dbfiddle... The first two Explains are the same, but that does not prove that they will be of equal speed.  (Explain is not detailed enough.)  Most of the rest of the queries involve two "ranges" in the Where or Order by; in most cases, this defeats the effective use of an index.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
select col3 from table
    where col1 = 'col1'
    order by col2
```

with `INDEX(col1, col2)` (which is called a "composite index")

I agree with you, not the quote.

To figure out what went wrong, please provide

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `table` -- so we can see exact datatypes and index
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table'; -- to see sizes
EXPLAIN SELECT ...;  -- to see what the Optimizer decide was best
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON select ...; -- more details

FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';  -- to get still more details.
```

and a link to the quote you provided.